# AS3 Asynchronism problems

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I had a strange bug in my program which I fortunately found quite quickly but am still puzzled why it was happening. Essentially it was to do with the order of commands in the  source code and event listeners, here is the example:

```
function detectFaces(loader:ImageLoader)
{
var detector:FaceDetector=new FaceDetector();
detector.addEventListener(FaceDetectorEvent.FACE_CROPPED,facesDetected);
detector.loadFaceImageFromBitmap(loader.bitmap);
var something:Number = stage.width;

    function facesDetected(e:FaceDetectorEvent):void{
          trace(something); 
    }
}
```

Operation that raise the event here is not important, only thing to note about it would be it takes around 100ms. What I get as trace output is NaN and I don't know why that is since line declaring the variable something will definitely be called before callback of facesDetected and it is in scope of the handler function declared under it. This problem was easy to solve by just moving var something:Number = stage.width; before  loadFaceImageFromBitmap(..) method,  but I would really like to know why this is happening?
I am suspecting this is not due to order of execution but has something to do with passingByValue and passingByRefrence deferences but don't know how would these cause an error like this.

EDIT: Now I am even more puzzled... This code works in any order of declaration:

```
timers();
function timers()
{
var timerTest:Timer = new Timer(100,1);
timerTest.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTime);
//BEFORE DECLARATION
    timerTest.start();
var something:Number = stage.width;

function onTime(e:Event)
{
    trace("SOMETHING :"+something);
}
}





timers();
function timers()
{
 var timerTest:Timer = new Timer(100,1);
 timerTest.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTime);

 var something:Number = stage.width;
 //AFTER  DECLARATION
 timerTest.start();
 function onTime(e:Event)
 {
    trace("SOMETHING :"+something);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to your initial question, actionscript will complete the execution of a block of code before it continues to execute subsequent lines. If there was nothing asynchronous happening in your loadFaceImageFromBitmap method (ie, if your weren't using a Loader or some other object that had to wait for an event to fire) then, however long the code takes to execute, the FACE_CROPPED event will still fire before 'something' is set to a value.

As for the other problem, it looks to me like the answer is simply that you're using a TimerEvent - Actionscript will acknowledge that it shouldn't wait for the event to fire before continuing to execute code; It will, therefore, declare 'something' before the 100 miliseconds passes. So, in this case, because you're using an event, the code WILL continue 'reading' and executing the lines following the event listener.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I get it now. The problem is that the event is fired in synchronous way and thus the function will be called before variable is set. I didn't write this detection function and am using a library and was thinking that it works like loader complete or similar. Am I correct to say that the code is frozen while detector.loadFaceImageFromBitmap(bitmap) is executing?

Comment: As you say, it depends if there's anything asynchronous happening in 'loadFace...'. If not then yes, actionscript will effectively 'wait' while it executes all of the code in that function before proceeding to the next line.

Comment: All is clear now ,thank you. I think I learned better not to make assumptions about code being asynchronous just because of the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

The code of the function `loadFaceImageFromBitmap` run on a sync way. The `FaceDetectorEvent.FACE_CROPPED` event listener is invoked inside of that function, it is not a callback declared to run after some response is returned for ie(http request).

In the case of the `Timer` it works as expected, because event listener is not invoked right at the start moment, it waits for X time.

Comment: This did point me in the right direction so thank you. You get the upvote from me but the accepted answer is more detailed.